# How to Update Label With Downloading Data

Tags: ios, objective-c, multithreading, uilabel, protocols

In my model, data is downloaded from website in a for loop and in a each turn data is sending to my viewController using protocol method. In model file;

```
    for(NSString* data in DataArray){

        [self.delegate passUpdatingCourse:data_name];

 //other operations
}
```

In my viewController data name coming from model is saving to NSArray property in other thread;

```
    ModelClass *modelObject = [[ModelClass alloc]  init];
    [modelObject setDelegate:self];

    dispatch_queue_t otherQ = dispatch_queue_create("Q", NULL);

    dispatch_async(otherQ, ^{

        //other operations

        [self performSelectorOnMainThread:@selector(passUpdatingCourse:) withObject:nil waitUntilDone:YES];


        dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{

            [self.myIndicator stopAnimating];
            self.indicatorText.hidden = YES;
            [self.changingCourseLabel setNeedsDisplay];

        });


    });
```

And also data coming via protocol method is setting viewController label;

```
-(void)passUpdatingCourse:(NSString *)data_in{

    self.myLabel.text = data_in;

}
```

When each data came, myLabel in a viewController must be update. But it is not happens. In a protocol method when I use this;

```
NSLog(@"Data:%@",self.myLabel.text);
```

Yeah it shows data in a console but myLabel in a view is not changing.

I searched questions like that but couldn't find a solution.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming your loop is on a background thread, dispatch your label updates to the main queue (async).

If you're inside a `for` loop on the main thread nothing is going to get updated in the UI until your method returns and dispatch won't help in that case.